# maven-pax-plugin: Select start level

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-felix, pax

Hey guys i believe it is a simple issue but i cant find anything:

How is it possible to specify the run levels for my bundles using the maven-pax-plugin?

(I call mvn pax:provision from the command line)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a part of [pax-runner provision settings](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxrunner/Provisioning)

e.g

> mvn:com.acme/foo/1.0.0@5

Comment: Hello Dmytro, unfourtenatly the homepage of the pax team is down and i cant get it to work... I have tried mvn pax:provision bundle@6 but nothing happend. Can you please provide me an concrete example?

Comment: 1. what did you expect from run level 6?
2. what is default framework run level?

Comment: The situation is as follow: I am using different bundles which register a Service via DS. In another Bundle i have something like services = Activator.getContext().getAllServiceReferences(foo,
     null); And i am getting a null Pointer exception. As far as i understand thats becaus all Bundles have the same start level. Because the pax:plugin specifies  level 1 for OSGI and 5 for all other Bundles i came up with 6

Comment: is Activator.getContext() static? Are you sure that you use this code after BundleActivator.start() and you assigned BundleContext correctly to this static field?

Comment: Yeah my Activator looks like following: private static BundleContext context;

 public static BundleContext getContext() {
  return context;
 }@Override
 public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws      Exception {
  
  Activator.context = bundleContext; In another class i am using something like this: services = Activator.getContext().getAllServiceReferences(name,
     null);

Comment: Is another class a part of the bundle? Try to refactor your code to avoid static references of BundleContext - it's an OSGi bad-smell.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this. I've got this one from an Eclipse Plugin... But that still left me with my problem: Maybe Start Levels are the wrong approach. What i want: I have an Interface and multiple Implementations registered via DS with some Properties, each in an own Bundle (one for the interace and lets say 5 different implentating). I then want to look up all Services registered via that interface and then match the one exact one via the properties file. But my Bundles all have the default Start Level 5 und so i always get an NPE in my "LookUp" Bundle.

Comment: In this case, you can use DS to handle references of all registered services: by class name and target filter. DS engine will provide you all references if you describe them correctly.

Comment: Ok i will give it a try. Thank you very much for pointing into the right direction

Comment: @DmytroPishchukhin How do I specify this setting when using the pax-provision plugin (and not pax-runner directly)

Comment: Found it. It goes as a param in the pax-plugin configuration like this: `<param>mvn:org.apache.cxf.dosgi/cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution/1.3.1@start:10</param>`